Why is extra Biblical evidence a must for every answer?
In a recent conversation I had with a moderator, I learned that it is mandatory for every answer to include a non-Biblical source(s) as reference, even if the poster has clearly stated he or she needs Biblical references as response. The reason for this, the site does not accept personal interpretations of the Bible. Why is extra Biblical evidence a must for every answer for contributors like me who trust the Bible more than any Christian blog or article available online?

Why is extra Biblical evidence a must for every answer?
The reason for this, the site does not accept personal interpretations of the Bible.
First of all is this is a question and answer site and not a forum that is designed to receive personal opinions.
Answers to questions must be able to be substantiated by facts and supportable evidence. Theological traditions, customs and even theological opinions must be able to be supported by real theological studies, otherwise there is a chance that our our personal opinions will be expressed in the answer box.
Theological opinions must be substantiated by real theological studies by real theologians of a particular denomination. Otherwise its our own opinions in play and are frowned upon here.
This site requires fact based posts as best we can.
If you desire to express your opinions on the Bible, please go to a Christian forum or blog to convey your message.
Answers can not be answered by direct Biblical texts only and require some reference from a theologian. Remember well that bible verse only answers can be very flawed posts as translations very greatly and thus their interpretation can be hotly debated. Thus supporting evidence is required.
Once again this is a question and answer site and not a forum for discussion on biblical subjects.

Thanks for your answer, so even for the simplest of questions that can be answered by direct Biblical evidence require some reference from a theologian ?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany we're prefer to not have simple questions here - or at least not the simplest of questions.  "Who Built the Ark?" LMGTFY

@PeterTurner, got it. What if the external source is biased or what if there is no theologian in that denomination?

If there's no theologian in the denomination, then there's a chance that it is not a real question.  Or you can answer from first principles.

@PeterTurner, define a real question? What makes a question real? I do believe any question asked is real

@SoFewAgainstSoMany real questions have answers I vehemently disagreed with this premise when we were starting programmer.SE, but the point of Christianity.SE is not subjectivity.

We don't strictly require references in every answer; people often write answers on the go, and some things can be considered general knowledge. But if challenged, answerers must be prepared to add references.
It's important to understand that the subject matter of this site is the documented teachings of Christian denominations and movements. Personal beliefs are not what this site is about, and answers are not always written by someone who believes the teachings they explain. That's why the ideal answer is one that

Clearly identifies the position being discussed (if the question is open to more than one denomination)
Explains the teachings clearly and fairly in neutral language
Gives conclusive supporting evidence from reputable sources

Questions can't just ask for personal beliefs, and those that do will be closed.
The main issue with a recent Q&A was on a question scoped to non-Trinitarianism, none of the nine answers it received even identified which form of non-Trinitarianism they represented. That question in particular needs referenced answers because despite being scoped to non-Trinitarianism, it asks about something most Trinitarians would also agree with. The question asker seems to think it is a sticking point, though I don't really know why. But that means that more than usual we really need clear references to know that an answer is actually valid. When the question asker is complaining about Trinitarian answers being written on their question (which is fair), then non-Trinitarian answers need to prove it. If an answer looks Trinitarian to me, and it doesn't give any references showing that it's actually the teachings of a non-Trinitarian denomination, then I'm pretty much obliged to remove it.

Thanks for your answer, I agree that adding the extra Biblical reference improves the overall quality of an answer and will always do some research on a question. + 1 Upvote
